# Trying to match a name inside an email

Tags: perl

I am grabbing an email from a server and trying to match it from an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@array = qw/will steve frank john/;

$match = “Steve <stevewilliams@email.com>"; # has to be full name and email
if (grep /$match/, @array) {
      print "found it\n";
    }else{
      print "no match\n";
    }
exit
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you want to use `"` instead of your `“` quote?

Comment: Yes, dunno how that got there

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I match steve to that email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match on will and steve:

Your method was looking for the full text "Steve stevewilliams@email.com" in the array but it does not exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @array = qw/will steve frank john/;

my $match = 'Steve <stevewilliams@email.com>'; # has to be full name and email

if ( my @found = grep { $match =~ /$_/ } @array ) {
    # it's there
    print "Match: \n\t@found\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Match: 
    will steve
```

Answer (score -1):

There are probably a zillion ways to to this in Perl.
I would use a regular expression to trim the email out of what your trying to match since your list is just names.
Then use lc to lowecase the name ($match), since your list is all lower case.
If you happen to need $match to remain unchanged you could use a hash to keep track of everything.
I had to use a backslash in-front of the @ in the example email, but I think in your real program you wont need to worry about that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my @array = qw/will steve frank john/;

my $match = "Steve <stevewilliams\@email.com>"; # has to be full name and email
# regex to trim name from email \s gets the whitespace if any.
$match =~ s/\s?\<.*$//g;
#lower case it
$match = lc($match);
print "'$match'\n";
if (grep /$match/, @array) {
      print "found it\n";
    }else{
      print "no match\n";
    }
exit;
```

Comment: That actually works well but is it possible to match on anything in that string what we have now and the name before the email "Steve"? Thank you very much for this.